# Phonegap eclipse, computer crashes to blue screen immediately after apk export and install onto phone

Tags: android, windows, eclipse, cordova

Looking to see if anyone else has experienced this situation whereby immediately after the app is run to debug on the connected phone the computer will crash to blue screen.

It does appear as the code was successfully exported into .apk format, and installed onto the phone, at which point the blue screen happens.

The app I'm making is utilising two pieces of javascript scripts.

To add, when running the application to emulator, it will run smoothly.

Anyone experience something like this?

Comment: Sounds like a kernel module error. Try to see what is crashing http://www.simple-talk.com/sysadmin/general/troubleshooting-windows-blue-screen-errors/

Comment: Lots of people experience lots of BSOD's, it's a Windows rite of passage.. unavoidable. Luckily the key to solving the issue is usually right in front of you as long as the Blue screen is up. Look for the offending driver file about 3 - 4 lines from the top. It sounds like in your case it could be related to your Phone's usb driver on your computer. You could try to reinstall that driver or update it. How about some more info?? Windows version and Phone make and model.

Comment: After having reproduced the error twice, the third time running eclipse has so far been blue-screenless after restart. In the first two instances, I was also running Github (the windows application, not the gitbash/gitgui) . It was surprising to note that when attempting to clone onto the laptop to reproduce the error, it eclipse could not see the project. Suspicious.
As for more info, windows 7 64bit, Nexus S. 4.0.4

Comment: Try using the same code base on a different PC.

Comment: Even I am facing issue. I am using HTC Incredible S for developement.I am running windows 7 64 bit Professional. Whenever I am connect my phone thru USB cable within 10-15 minute I get the blue Screen. Any solution ?